# What is the behaviour of GA without ECHO? (telnet)

Tags: telnet, specifications, rfc

When GA (suppress go-ahead), but not remote ECHO is negotiated, the client program is not sending anything, as expected, but also doesn't interpret any characters. Thus backspace isn't working, but even pressing enter doesn't send anything.

For example typing `a DEL a ENTER` produces:

```
a^?a^M
```

As enter isn't interpreted, I am unable to send anything to the server.

I haven't found anything regarding this in a RFC. What is the intended behavior?